# How To apply media query in table?

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design

I created one site it is working as a Non Responsive site right now.
I used table structure format. 
Now I am planning to make it full Responsive?
Is there any way change from table structure to full Responsive Site? 
Any idea or any method on how to do it.

Below is my Table structure code :

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>LearningFox</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body{
    bgcolor:#FFFFFF;
    TOPMARGIN:0;
    LEFTMARGIN:0;
    RIGHTMARGIN:0;
}

table.responsive{
    width:100%;
    border:0;
    cellpadding:0;
    cellspacing:0;
}

</style>
</head>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" RIGHTMARGIN="0">

<table class="responsive">

<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="800" height="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr bgcolor="#366C88">
    <td colspan="2"  style="background-image:url('../site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;" width="100%" height="100" align="right">
<TABLE BORDER="0"  CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="190" >
    <TR>
        <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000">Logged in as: <B><?php echo $lms_username; ?></B></TD>
    </TR>
        <?php
        if($lms_groups=="on" && $lms_user_group!=""){
        ?>
        <TR>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo"$lms_gtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_group</B>";}?></TD>        
        </TR>   
        <TR>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php echo "$lms_sgtitle: "; if($lms_groups=="on"){echo"<B>$lms_user_subgroup</B>";}?></TD>

        </TR>   
        <tr>
            <TD><FONT FACE="VERDANA" SIZE="1" COLOR="#000000"><?php if($section=="reports" && $report){echo"<A HREF='index.php?section=reports&sid=$sid'>Back to Detailed Reports Section";}?></FONT></TD>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>

    </TABLE>
    <?php

    }
    ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="20" bgcolor="" background="images/bg.gif"><table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <TD align="right"><?php
    if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
    {
    ?><a style=""  href="index.php?section=<?php echo $section; ?>&logout=YES&sid=<?php echo $sid; ?>"><img src="images/logout.png" border="0" align="ABSMIDDLE" alt="Click here to Log Out"></a><?php
    }
    ?></TD>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="198"><!---------BEGIN SIDE NAV TABLE-------------><table width="198" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr valign="top"> 
          <td width="198"><?php
                if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
                {
                    include($dir_components."navbar2.php");
                }
                ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php
            /*
                if(!is_null($sid)&&$session_error=="none")
                {
                    include($dir_components."tech.php");
                }
            */
                ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
    <!--<td class="boxcontent" VALIGN="TOP" width="602" style="border:1px solid red;">-->
    <td class="boxcontent" VALIGN="TOP" >
    <?php 
    include($mysection);
    echo("$mysection");
    ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="bottom" id="copyright"><hr>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you build it in tables to begin with? Also your tables have a lot of inline items like width and height. You may as well start from the beginning and make it with `<div>`

Comment: its not my project handle only correction now client want to responsive site ..its created 6 year before sir

Comment: Andrew is right, you really ought to redesign the whole layout without tables. But in addition to that, perhaps you could be more specific about what you are looking for: how do you want the website to respond? "Responsive" is a popular term to throw around, but it doesn't mean anything very specific.

Comment: I'm afraid you can not make table responsive. because table element is not a responsive element

Comment: If it was made 6 years ago charge them for a new website and build it from the ground up or they will have to stick with what they already have. Make financial sense for them and you.

Comment: @Andrew any way change it responsive ?  i have to change all code in div tag its correct than  i should apply media query  in css

Comment: Yeah you need to completely rebuild the full website. But you can build it how you like. You may as well update other things for them as its been 6 years since they last had there website updated. The web has moved a lot in 6 years.

Comment: sure @ Andrew  i will change all site div tag and apply css code